# Drip Campaign with Time-based Workflow

Tags: time-dependent-workflow

I have set up a simple 'drip email marketing campaign' in Salesforce utilizing a time based workflow.

I added a checkbox to the leads page that reads "Send Drip Emails". There is a workflow that will evaluate and check this box.

Here is a screenshot of the workflow:

[image]

I have another time-based workflow that checks when this checkbox gets checked, and kicks off the workflow. Here is what that workflow looks like:

[image]

For some reason, leads that matched this criteria are not being sent emails. I checked the queue for time based workflows and did not return anything:

[image]

What I am doing wrong?

Also, I added a task to be added so I can see when the email is being sent so that I can see it on the lead record. This is assigned to our sales leader, as I don't think it's possible to assign it to the record owner (person who the email is sent from).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

On the field update for your checkbox, did you mark the "re-evaluate workflow Rules after Field Change?"

If that's not marked, your WFR isn't triggering your Time-Based WFR and therefore your emails aren't being sent

Comment: Great suggestion, did this fix it Paul?

Comment: Yes, this fixed it! Thanks very much Brian. One of my users tried to convert something that was queued and couldn't so this isn't a long term fix. It will work until we get Hubspot going! Thanks again!